# flutter redux state changed without dispatching actions

Tags: flutter, redux, bloc, flutter-redux

I'm using redux and bloc together.
I have a edit profile screen and I get initial value from redux state and then change values in bloc.
But when my bloc state changed, redux state change too without dispatching action.
I want to change redux state when user submit edited values.
here is my first part of build method:

```
return StoreConnector<AppState, Store<AppState>>(
  converter: (store) => store,
  builder: (context, store) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBar,
      body: BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => EditUserProfileBloc(
          editEditUserProfileRepository: repository,
        )..add(
            EditUserProfileScreenLoaded(
              userProfile: store.state.userProfile,
            ),
          ),
        child: BlocListener<EditUserProfileBloc, EditUserProfileState>(
          listener: (context, state) async {},
          child: BlocBuilder<EditUserProfileBloc, EditUserProfileState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              _bloc = BlocProvider.of<EditUserProfileBloc>(context);
                ...
```

and my widget to show and change image:

```
ImageSelect(
    onSelect: (img) => _bloc.add(
        EditUserProfileImageChanged(imgSrc: img),
    ),
    child: Avatar(imgSrc: state.userProfile.avatar),
),
```

and my bloc:

```
if (event is EditUserProfileImageChanged) {
    UserProfile newUserProfile = state.userProfile;

    yield EditUserProfileBeforeTotalChanged();
    newUserProfile.avatar = event.imgSrc;
    yield EditUserProfileTotalState(userProfile: newUserProfile);
}
```

here when I change avatar without saving, other places I use avatar change too.